# save image to path from temporary storage

Tags: react-native

im trying to save an image from URI to my internal mobile storage and upload to and external storage i can upload it just fine but cant save an image from my uri

```
  const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
  if (status === 'granted') {
    const result: any = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: Platform.OS === 'android' ? false : true,
      aspect: [4, 4],
      quality: 0.3
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) props.userProfileUploadImage(result.uri);
  } else {
    Alert.alert(null, `${Hallo.translator('General')['AlertAllowCam']}`);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)  to save file from `uri`

```
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const imagePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${new Date().toISOString()}.jpg`.replace(/:/g, '-');

if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS(response.origURL, imagePath, 0, 0)
        .then(res => {})
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('ERROR: image file write failed!!!');
            console.log(err.message, err.code);
        });
} else if(Platform.OS === 'android') {
    RNFS.copyFile(response.uri, imagePath)
        .then(res => {})
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('ERROR: image file write failed!!!');
            console.log(err.message, err.code);
        });
}
```

Details [Here](https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/react-native/react-native-fs/)